# type mismatch resolving <impl std::future::Future as std::future::Future>::Output == std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to implement an API class using `wasm_bindgen` with asynchronous calls.

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use std::future::Future;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture;
use js_sys::Promise;
use web_sys::{Request, RequestInit, RequestMode, Response};
use wasm_bindgen_futures::future_to_promise;

use crate::fetch_example::*;


#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct API {
    root: String,
}


#[wasm_bindgen]
impl API {
    pub fn new(root: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            root: root.to_string(),
        }
    }

    pub fn getVersion(&self) -> Promise {
        let url = format!("{}/version", self.root);

        future_to_promise(async move {
            _request_json(&url, "GET")
        })
    }

    // other methods ...
}


// What is the correct returned type instead of Result<JsValue, JsValue> ???
async fn _request_json(url: &str, method: &str) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
    opts.method(method);
    opts.mode(RequestMode::Cors);

    let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(&url, &opts)?;

    request.headers().set("Accept", "application/json")?;

    let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
    let resp_value = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request)).await?;

    let resp: Response = resp_value.dyn_into().unwrap();

    let json = JsFuture::from(resp.json()?).await?;

    Ok(json)
}
```

As it is seen, I took out the HTTP call into a separate private function `_request_json` to avoid code duplication in different API methods (they are supposed to be several, not `getVersion` only).

I took the base example of an HTTP call from here: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/fetch.html

Also I found that asynchronous calls of struct methods should be implemented with the help of `future_to_promise`: https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1858

**So the issue is with the returned type by `_request_json`. I cannot guess it correctly.**

When I compile the project I get the error:

```
type mismatch resolving `<impl std::future::Future as std::future::Future>::Output == std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>`
```

If I copy the body of `_request_json` inside of `future_to_promise` everything works fine.

What is the correct returned expression for `_request_json` to make the code works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction:

```
async move {
    _request_json(&url, "GET")
}
```

has the type `impl Future<Output = impl Future<Output = Result<JsValue, JsValue>>>`.

You can fix it like this:

```
future_to_promise(async move {
    _request_json(&url, "GET").await
})
```

and *probably* also like this:

```
future_to_promise(_request_json(&url, "GET"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is quite clear.